# Best practice for forwarding ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` that contains - among other things - a `ListView`.  The `ListView` has a different data context than the `UserControl` (this data context is not exposed).  If someone consumes my control, I would like them to be able to (indirectly) bind to the `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` dependency property.  It should really *feel* like the user is binding to a typical `ItemsSource`.

I'm not sure what the best way to proceed is.  Looking at how `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsSource` property worked in Reflector showed some logic that seemed a bit more involved than ought to be necessary for simple forwarding.

My current best idea is to expose a collection as a dependency property on the outer control and, when it is updated, update the `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`.  But I'm not sure what type this collection should be (should I require an `ObservableCollection<T>`, for example), or if there are any gotchas I should look out for.

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AddOwner to add your UserControl as an owner of the ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty. In the new property meta data, give a property changed callback that sets the ItemsSource of your ListView.